# Angular CLI- Couldn't find package @angular/animations on the npm registry

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm trying to create a new Angular CLI project, and am running into some trouble.

I have installed the CLI by running npm install -g @angular/cli, and am trying to create a brand new Angular 4 project. I'm running ng new tutorial-ng2-rest-service, following this tutorial:https://sniederm.wordpress.com/2017/04/12/tutorial-ng2-rest-service/

However, I am seeing the following error message in my Node.js command prompt:

error Couldn't find package "@angular/animations" on the "npm" registry.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: which version of angular you are using? can you update the package json please

Comment: Since I am just now creating the project I do not have a package.json file yet. Version of angular: @angular/cli@1.5.5

Comment: installation of `@angular/animations` inside your node_module will fix this

Comment: if your company uses it's own npm registry, you need to check your npmrc or yarnrc files to point to companies registry. and update proxies in npmrc files. 
at least in my case I solved this way.